# Android SQLite query syntax error

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am new to Android and SQLite.

I am preparing a code to find whether the given phone number (value given inside an EditText box) is present in the table or not.

I used the following code, but it shows error:

```
c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM "+ Dbasehelper.TABLE_NAME+
                      " WHERE "+ Dbasehelper.KEY_LNAME.toString()+" = " +
                       txtNum.getText().toString(),null);
```

The phone number is saved similar to the  following form 
example :

(775)758-96

The LogCat record :

```
04-29 08:56:09.085: D/OpenGLRenderer(5311): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-29 08:56:11.095: E/okstartr(5311): bdok
04-29 08:56:11.105: E/okstartr(5311): bdok
04-29 08:56:11.105: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(5311): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "655": syntax error, db=/data/data/com.pjct.waysafe/databases/WAS.db
04-29 08:56:11.105: D/AndroidRuntime(5311): Shutting down VM
04-29 08:56:11.105: W/dalvikvm(5311): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a5c1f8)
04-29 08:56:11.115: E/AndroidRuntime(5311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 08:56:11.115: E/AndroidRuntime(5311): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "655": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT count(*) FROM friends WHERE phone = (755) 655-745
04-29 08:56:11.115: E/AndroidRuntime(5311):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-29 08:56:11.115: E/AndroidRuntime(5311):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
04-29 08:56:11.115: E/AndroidRuntime(5311):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
```

Comment: pls post logcat to have us look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are inserting the *value* of `txtNum` directly into the SQL string, but SQL is a programming language where strings must be quoted.

To avoid formatting problems like this, you should use parameters:

```java
c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM "+ Dbasehelper.TABLE_NAME+
                      " WHERE "+ Dbasehelper.KEY_LNAME +" = ?",
                      new String[] { txtNum.getText() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this codes.

```
String sqlString = "SELECT count(*) FROM "+ Dbasehelper.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ Dbasehelper.KEY_LNAME+" = '" + txtNum.getText().toString()+"'";

    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sqlString, null);
    if (cursor != null & cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    // do some things

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

May be works. Hopefully. Best of Luck!

Answer (score -1):

Hi below is help for you

```
 //Get Row Count
 public int getCount() {
  String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEST;
  int count = 0;
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
  if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
   count = cursor.getCount();
   cursor.close();
  } 
  return count;
 }
```

if need more detail visit below link: [Android Sqlite Tutorial](http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/04/android-sqlite-with-custom-listview.html)